# About Interface Builder components release

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib

If I have some objects like UILabel, UIImageView, etc. on my XIB
But I don't using any IBOutlet to connect them
I reference these objects like follow

```
UILabel *label =  (UILabel *)[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:x];
UIImageView *imageView =  (UIImageView *)[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:x];
```

Do I need release this objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you don't call retain on it, then you don't have to release it.

However, your approach is very bad. Is any reason that stop your from creating IBOutlet connection? Even use `viewWithTag:` will do a better job. Because if you add a new view to nib, it is very likely to mess the order and you have to change every hardcoded index value.

Comment: if u use viewWithtag then it will be mandatory to have different tags for all items in the view.and since he is using same tag everywhere thats x for label and imageView it will crash the app

Comment: of course the tag must be unique. but at least it will not change if you accidentally click on IB and modified the order of views.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not retaining this objects you don't has to release them. You only has to release the object that you create

Answer (score 0):

You should release all the object what ever you created. it's good habit.

Otherwise you ll get memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not release it unless you alloc, init, retain, copy the object yourself.